# Google app engine Image upload removes previous files

Tags: google-app-engine

I am fairly new to Google App Engine. When I keep files in images folder and run bat file, it uploads images properly but when I remove those images and put new images to upload, it removes previous images.

My app.yaml looks like this

> ```
> application: testcdn
> version: 1
> runtime: python27
> api_version: 1
> threadsafe: true
>
> default_expiration: "1d 1h"
>
> handlers:
> - url: /css
>   static_dir: css
>
> - url: /images
>   static_dir: images
>
> - url: /js
>   static_dir: js
>
> - url: /.*
>   static_files: index.html
>   upload: index.html
> ```

Also when 2 developers try to upload images to the same cdn store with different google accounts, it removes images previously uploaded by other developer.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Your local files mirror your deployed files.  If you remove files locally, then deploy, the remote files will be deleted.  You are not just defining the files to upload, but the files to mirror remotely.

I am not sure about your 2nd comment.  Do the files have the same filenames?  You will have to provide the upload code for diagnosis.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have not written any code for this. I have installed google app engine and I have written a batch file which has code like -  "C:\Python27\python" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py" update "C:\testcdn"    This batch file checks my .yaml file and upload images to the cdn from my images folder. Is there any way to insert only new images instead of mirror image files.